# Add where clause argument if variable is set

Tags: mysql

I have a WHERE-clause in my SQL-query, and would like to add an argument depending on if the @Fran variable is set.

If @Fran is NULL, then it shouldn't filter the results at all. Otherwise, if @Fran is set, then it should add a WHERE clause "AND franid=@Fran". How could i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
AND ((@Fran IS NULL) OR (@Fran IS NOT NULL AND franid=@Fran));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked great!

Answer (score 0):

```
AND IFNULL(@Fran, franid) = franid
```

results in TRUE if `@Fran` is NULL (then it is essentially `franid = franid`) and in `@Fran = franid` if it is not NULL.